# How to display Google AdSense ads to search engine traffic only?

Tags: php, preg-match, adsense, http-referer

I want to display Google AdSense ads to search engine traffic only and NO ads to regular visitors coming in directly or from Facebook, Twitter, email link, etc...

Here's the code I currently use and it seems to work okay, but I want to also improve the code to include many other search engines in addition to Google such as Bing, Yahoo, Ask, etc.. Would someone mind looking at the code below and revise it with improvements?

```
<?php
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if (preg_match("(google|yahoo|bing)", $ref) != false) {
echo <<<END
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "xx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
/* xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xx xxxxxx */
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = xxx;
google_ad_height = xxx;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
</div>
END;
}
else {
     echo ""
;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code looks fairly good. My suggestions would be to use `/` rather than `(` as the pattern delimiter as parens can also be used for match groups. You can also add the `i` flag to make your matches case insensitive. There is no need for your else statement, as it just outputs and empty string. There is also an extra `</div>` tag in your `END` HEREDOC - you want to make sure that both the open and close are either inside or outside your `if` statement.

```
<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$my_domain = "example.com";
$search_engines = "google|yahoo|bing|altavista|digg";
$pattern = "((http(s)?:\/\/)(\w+?\.)?(?!{$my_domain})({$search_engines}))";
if (preg_match("/{$pattern}/i", $referrer) != false) {
    echo <<<END
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
    google_ad_client = "xx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    /* xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xx xxxxxx */
    google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    google_ad_width = xxx;
    google_ad_height = xxx;
    //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
    </script>
END;
} else {
    // Show something to visitors not referred by a search engine
}
?>
```

The regex pattern results in the following, matches marked with `*`:

```
FALSE - http://example.com/google
FALSE - http://example.com/google.com
FALSE - http://www.example.com/google.com
TRUE  - *http://google*.com/example.com
TRUE  - *http://www1.google*.com/example.com
TRUE  - *http://www.google*.com/example.com
TRUE  - *http://images.google*.com/page
TRUE  - *https://google*.com/example.com
TRUE  - *https://www.google*.com/example.com
```

Comment: Wow thanks! That's pretty cool to hear that I coded something "fairly good", that's awesome. And thank you very much for revising the code and for giving me such a great explanation. I really do appreciate that a lot. The if statement is to show something else to regular viewers. I think I can manage to add that back in. Thanks again doublesharp.

Comment: Hey @doublesharp I am getting this error:

I am getting this error message:
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting T_VARIABLE or T_END_HEREDOC or T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES or T_CURLY_OPEN in /var/www/xxxxx.com/public_html/xxx-xxx-xx.php on line 18`

Comment: Fixed it... the `END` can not be indented. Found the solution here: http://www.codingforums.com/showpost.php?s=f1da607bd751dc4213191c3d82624a4d&p=1253001&postcount=2

Comment: One thing I just discovered is that ads will be displayed if a visitor clicks on a link within the site that has the word google within the url structure.

Comment: Sorry about that... was just using the stackoverflow editor and missed that I had it indented. If you are planning on showing something different to non-search engine visitors, then certainly leave the `else` in, the only reason to remove it is if it's empty.

Comment: No apology needed! Hey if you have a moment, would you mind checking out the above comment regarding ads displaying when visitors click within the site on URL's that contain the word Google, Yahoo, etc.. in it (i.e http://yourname.com/page-about-google.php)

Comment: Ok, that one took me longer than it should have, but good to brush up on regex. I updated the answer to match patterns that are not preceded by your domain name, and will work for http/s as well as multiple hostnames.